# getmail does not keep track of downloaded emails if process is killed

Tags: email, backup, gmail, process, imap

I am using `getmail` to archive my Gmail account's inbox. However, every once in a while the process hangs -- probably due to a bad connection with Gmail's IMAP servers. I find that the only way to restart the process is to simply kill the process with CTRL+C. Sometimes, when killing and restarting the process, `getmail` is not updating the `oldmail` file which it uses, when it restarts, to determine which emails were previously downloaded. This makes the process take more time (and potentially hang once again), and bloats the `mbox` file that stores the backup data.

After poking around, it appears that `getmail` only updates the `oldmail` file when it completes -- and so if it is unexpectedly killed, the data on which emails have already been downloaded is lost. Is there a way to force `getmail` to update the `oldmail` database in real time, rather than just at the end of the process?

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding getmail**

The [getmail FAQ](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/faq.html#faq-how-maxpersession) reads like this behaviour is "kind of" known:

> Use the max_messages_per_session option to limit the number of messages getmail will process in a single session. Some users with flaky servers use this option to reduce the chances of seeing messages more than once if the server dies in mid-session.

**Possible workaround**

A (GMail specific) possible workaround, that completely gets rid of the need for the oldmail file, is to introduce a kind of "archive bit":

- Create a custom label, e.g. named `archive`
- Create a filter to apply this label to any new message (received or sent)

  - `(from:(you@gmail.com) OR to:(you@gmail.com))`
- Using an IMAP retriever, only fetch mails from this label's folder (`mailboxes` option)
- Set the `delete` option in the config (in GMail, this will only remove the label)